# Reading a file backwards in Mathematica -- How?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a large file (written in Mathematica) that contains n "records" and each of these records is a list of fixed length m, where n > 10,000 and 500 < m < 600 (bytes). Note, my system does not have the capacity to hold all records in memory --- the reason for writing them to a file. I have an application (in Mathematica) that needs to process these records in reverse order; i.e. the last record written out is the first record to be processed. How can I read these records from the file in reverse order?

Meanwhile (after some trial and error with Mathematica I/O) I found one solution. Note, this is a stripped down example of a possible solution.

```
    fname = "testfile";

    strm = OpenWrite[fname];
    n = 10; (* In general, n could be very large *)
    For[k = 1, k <= n, k++,
      (* Create list on each pass through this loop ... *)

      POt = {{k, k + 1}, {k + 2, k + 3}};
      Print[POt];

      (* Save to a file *)
      Write[strm, POt];
    ];
    Close[strm];

    (* 2nd pass to get byte offsets of each record written to file *)
    strm = OpenRead[fname];
    ByteIndx = {0};
    For[i = 1, i <= n, i++,
      PIn = Read[strm];
      AppendTo[ByteIndx, StreamPosition[strm]];
    ];
    Drop[ByteIndx, -1]

    (* Read records in reverse order *)
    For[i = n, i >= 1, i--,
      SetStreamPosition[strm, ByteIndx[[i]]];
      PIn = Read[strm];
      Print[PIn];

      (* Process PIn ... *)

    ];
    Close[strm];
```

It would be nice if the 2nd pass (to get the byte offsets) could be eliminated but I have not found how to do this yet... Also, these byte offsets could be written to a file (similar to how the records are handled) and then read back in one at a time, should there still be a memory problem.

Comment: This leaves me thinking that I'd use an o/s utility to reverse sort the file then read it in Mathematica.

Comment: In your example each record is a mathematica expression. Is that really reflecting what you are actually trying to read? If so I'd think your general approach is the best you can do (if you reverse sort you wont likely have valid expressions to simply Read[].)

Comment: I am not sure how to interpret your comment. However, I can now say that I have implemented this approach in my Kalman filtering and RTS smoother application in which the records are the KF estimates of the covariance matrix, and it works rather well. Although, I still have yet to figure out how to eliminate the 2nd pass. Any suggestions that you may have George would be appreciated.

Comment: I was commenting on HPM's comment. In general when you Write[] an expression the result will span multiple lines in the output file. If you reverse sort by lines the result will be garbage, or at least a bigger problem the unravel than your first solution.  IF each record is guaranteed to be only one line then it is a good way to go.

Comment: If you open with PageWidth->Infinity in the writing code you should get all single line records, in case modifying the input is an option.

Comment: Following each record with a static size representation of that record's length would making reading the file backwards in one pass a lot easier. An example would be `(*0571*)`

Answer (score 0):

for sake of putting an answer, your second pass can be written concisely:

```
strm = OpenRead[fname];
ByteIndx=Reap[While[Sow[StreamPosition[strm]]; !TrueQ[Read[strm ] == EndOfFile]]][[2,1,;;-2]]
n=Length[ByteIndx]
```